# Change css dynamically from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new with ASP.NET MVC, at the cshtml I have some style:

```
 .circle {
     border: 2px solid red;
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     height: 100px;
     border-radius:50%;
     width: 100px;
 }

<div class="circle"></div>
```

And I want to change the circle position from the controller, I can I achieve that? In the controller I need something like:

```
circle.MarginLeft = 120;
```

Comment: You'd put it in your model (or the viewbag) and the cshtml would reference e.g. model.CircleMarginLeft when declaring the style info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your model or `ViewBag`.

In controller pass your data into an object like `circle.MarginLeft = 12` or use `ViewBag['marginLeft'] = 12`

and in your `.cshtml` file set

```
<div class="circle" style="margin-left:@ViewBag.marginLeft"></div>
```

or

```
<div class="circle" style="margin-left:@Model.marginLeft"></div>
```